# Generic Multi-Level Filter for WebApi in C# using Expression Tree, Issue with Nullable Sub Properties

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-web-api, filter, expression

I am making a generic multi-level filter for my WebApi in C#. However i keep getting the following error:

**Expression of type 'System.Void' cannot be used for return type 'System.Boolean'**

I believe the error happens when a sub property is nullable. For exemple, if i have Entity.SubEntity.description and i filter on description when SubEntity is null, then the error happens. However if the SubEntity is not null, then it works fine.

Other important information:

- For the filterDto, the value property can either be an array or a
  string.
- **The error happens when i convert Queryable.ToList() after the return of the Filter function.**
- Order of calls Filter() -> CompileFilter() -> CompileComparison()

I am not that good with Expression Trees, so i know i am missing some notions here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code Snippet:

```
public partial class FilterDto
{
    public string property { get; set; }
    public dynamic value { get; set; }
    public string @operator { get; set; }
    public bool exactMatch { get; set; }
}

public IQueryable<TEntity> Filter(IQueryable<TEntity> queryable, ICollection<FilterDto> filterDtoCollection, Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> filterProperty)
{
    if ((filterDtoCollection == null) || (filterDtoCollection.Count <= 0))
        return queryable;

    Expression filterExpression = null;
    ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "x");
    Expression ie = GetDeepPropertyExpression(pe, filterProperty.GetMemberName());
    Type includePropertyType = filterProperty.Body.Type;
    var comparisons = filterDtoCollection.Where(x => includePropertyType.GetProperty(x.property) != null).Select(x => CompileFilter(Expression.Property(ie, x.property), x));

    if (comparisons != null && comparisons.Count() > 0)
        filterExpression = comparisons.Aggregate((x, y) => Expression.AndAlso(x, y));
    else
        return queryable;

    Func<TEntity, Boolean> expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, Boolean>>(filterExpression, pe).Compile();
    return queryable.Where(expression).AsQueryable();
}

private Expression CompileFilter(Expression property, FilterDto filterDto)
{

    Expression filterExpression = null;
    Expression comparison = null;
    if (filterDto.value.GetType() != typeof(JArray))
    {
        filterExpression = CompileComparison(property, filterDto.value, filterDto.@operator, filterDto.exactMatch);
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (dynamic filterValue in filterDto.value)
        {
            dynamic value = Convert.ChangeType(filterValue.Value, property.Type);
            comparison = CompileComparison(property, value, filterDto.@operator, filterDto.exactMatch);

            if (filterExpression == null)
            {
                filterExpression = comparison;
            }
            else
            {
                if (filterDto.@operator == "in" || filterDto.@operator == "like")
                    filterExpression = Expression.OrElse(filterExpression, comparison);
                else
                    filterExpression = Expression.AndAlso(filterExpression, comparison);
            }
        }
    }

    return filterExpression;
}

private Expression CompileComparison(Expression property, dynamic value, string @operator, bool exactMatch)
{
    Expression comparison = null;
    Expression constant = Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(value), property.Type); 
    MethodInfo method = null;

    switch (@operator)
    {
        case "<":
            comparison = Expression.LessThan(property, constant);
            break;
        case "<=":
            comparison = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(property, constant);
            break;
        case "=":
            comparison = Expression.Equal(property, constant);
            break;
        case "&gt;=":
            comparison = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(property, constant);
            break;
        case "&gt;":
            comparison = Expression.GreaterThan(property, constant);
            break;
        case "!=":
            comparison = Expression.NotEqual(property, constant);
            break;
        case "in":
            comparison = Expression.Equal(property, constant);
            break;
        case "like":
            if (value.GetType() == typeof(String))
            {
                method = typeof(ExtensionMethods).GetMethod("Contains");
                comparison = Expression.Call(null, method, property, Expression.Constant(value), Expression.Constant(StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            }
            else
            {
                comparison = Expression.Equal(property, constant);
            }
            break;
        default:
            if (!exactMatch && value.GetType() == typeof(String))
            {
                method = typeof(ExtensionMethods).GetMethod("Contains");
                comparison = Expression.Call(null, method, property, Expression.Constant(value.ToString()), Expression.Constant(StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            }
            else
            {
                comparison = Expression.Equal(property, constant);
            }
            break;
    }

    return comparison;
}

private Expression GetDeepPropertyExpression(Expression initialInstance, IList<string> property)
{
    Expression result = null;
    foreach (string propertyName in property)
    {
        Expression instance = result;
        if (instance == null)
            instance = initialInstance;
        result = Expression.Property(instance, propertyName);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Why are you accepting an `IQueryable` if you're just going to call the `IEnumerable` methods on it?  Just accept an `IEnumerable` in the first place.  If you're using EF instead of LINQ to objects then the queries will work as intended even if there is no related entity.  SQL propagates `null` rather than throwing.

Comment: I read that IQueryable is much faster since it executes its query in SQL rater then in memory which IEnumerable does...

Comment: That's true, if you actually treated the query as an `IQueryable`.  You're casting it to an `IEnumerable`, adding a LINQ to Objects query, and then creating an `IQueryable` wrapper for that LINQ to objects query.  If you actually used `IQueryable` methods you'd need to do none of this and it would all not only work, but do the work in SQL and not filter in memory, as your code does.

Comment: Your talking about this line ?
return queryable.Where(expression).AsQueryable()

Comment: That is the line where you call a LINQ to objects query and then wrap that query in an `IQueryable`, yes.

Comment: Ok so i completely removed the wrapper AsQueryable(), however when i then convert The Enumerable to toList().... i get the System.NullReferenceException error. So i believe the error is deeper.. (Object reference not set to an instance of an object”)

Comment: Doing that results in code that's functionally identical to what you have.  It wouldn't fix anything, it's just not lying to the caller of your method and clamining to treat the `IQueryable` as an `IQueryable` when you aren't.  The correct solution to your problem is to just treat the `IQueryable` as an actual `IQueryable`.  When you do that you won't have any need to check for `null`.

Comment: Alright so if i understand, this is what i should write instead of what i have?
Queryable.Where(ctx.Customers, lambda)...

Comment: That should get you started.

Comment: Is there anything else you see might be wrong in the code that i posted apart from the Queryable situation?

Comment: The fact that the entire thing is building up a bunch of null checks needlessly.  None of that code needs to be there at all.

Comment: Null checks? you mean when i check to see if the property exists? By the way, you should write the answer below so i can accept it...

Comment: The answer is found Here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby-on-ienumerablet][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby-on-ienumerablet